# Problema al intentar guardar múltiples registros en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un problema al guardar múltiples datos en mi base de datos en mysql.

El problema es que al momento de seleccionar unos checkbox no me guarda, si por ejemplo seleccione 2. Me guarda solo 1 y el de id más bajo. Me explico.

Tengo 15 checkbox en total cuyo id va en incremento. (1,2,3,4) respectivamente.
Estos se muestran de manera definida según la opción de un `select`.

Por ejemplo, el select tiene los siguientes datos.

```
<select id="complejos" name="SelectComplejos" required="required">

   <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
   @foreach($complejo as $complejo)
   <option value="{{$complejo->id}}" name="ListaComplejos">{{$complejo->nombre}}</option>   

   @endforeach
 </select>
```

Al seleccionar la 1era opcion del select se muestran 3 checkbox cuyo id son, respectivamente:

```
checkbox| id
-------------
check 1 = 0
check 2 = 1
check 3 = 9
```

Luego al seleccionar los 3, en mi base de datos se deberían guardar de esta manera en mi tabla Horarios.

```
/*Tengo mas de 1000 registros por lo que empezaré con un número alto*/

id  |fecha_inicio        |fecha_termino       |estado       |checkbox_id
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
4000|2017-12-24 20:45:00 |2017-12-30 21:00:00 |No Disponible|         4
4001|2018-10-30 08:00:00 |2018-10-31 09:00:00 |Ocupado      |         0
4002|2018-10-30 08:00:00 |2018-10-31 09:00:00 |Ocupado      |         1
4003|2018-10-30 08:00:00 |2018-10-31 09:00:00 |Ocupado      |         9
```

Pero no sucede solo se guarda 1 y de id más bajo quedando de esta manera como resultado:

```
id  |fecha_inicio        |fecha_termino       |estado       |checkbox_id
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
4000|2017-12-24 20:45:00 |2017-12-30 21:00:00 |No Disponible|         4
4001|2018-10-30 08:00:00 |2018-10-31 09:00:00 |Ocupado      |         0
```

Si fuera otro grupo por ejemplo los de **`id`** 5, 6 y 3 respectivamente. Se me habría guardado el **`id`** de valor **`3`.**

Este es mi controlador.

```
public function store(Request $request){

    try {

        foreach ($request->get('sel') as $key => $value) {

            $horarios = new HorariosNew();

            $horarios->id = $request->get('id')[$key];

            $horarios->hora_inicio = $request->get('desde')[$key].' '.$request->get('sel')[$key];

            $horarios->hora_fin = $request->get('hasta')[$key].' '.$request->get('sel2')[$key];
            $horarios->estado_horario_id = $request->get('estado_horario_id')[$key];
            $horarios->cancha_id = $request->get('check')[$key];
            $horarios->save();

        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {

         Session::flash('error', 'Hubo un error desconocido, no se pudo registrar el horario');
         return redirect()->route('horarios.store');

    }

        Session::flash('message', 'Se agregó correctamente el horario');
        return redirect()->route('horarios.store');

}
```

Y esta es la Vista.

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=> 'horarios.store','method'=> 'POST','name'=>'horario', 'id'=>'horario_id', 'files' => true] ) !!}

    <div>

        /*INPUT DONDE EXTRAIGO EL ULTIMO ID DE MI TABLA HORARIOS*/
        <input type="number" name="id[]" value="{{$last_horario->id}}" readonly="readonly">


        <label>Complejos</label>
        <br>
        <label>Seleccione un complejo</label>
        <br>

        /*ESTE SELECT NO SE GUARDA PERO LOS CHECKBOX SI*/
        <select id="complejos" name="SelectComplejos" required="required" onchange="MuestraCanchas(event)">

            <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
            @foreach($complejo as $complejo)
            <option value="{{$complejo->id}}" name="ListaComplejos">{{$complejo->nombre}}</option>   

            @endforeach
        </select>
        <br><br>



            /*CHECKBOX*/    
            <div class="DivCheckCanchas" id="DivCheckCanchas">
                <label>* Seleccione una cancha o campo</label>
                <br><br>
                @foreach($campos as $campos)
                <div id="DivCanchas" class="DivCanchas">

                    /*______________*/
                    <input type="checkbox" data-complejo="{{$campos->complejo_id}}" id="{{$campos->nombre}}" value="{{$campos->id}}" name="check[]">
                    <label id="LabelCanchas" for="{{$campos->nombre}}">{{$campos->nombre}}</label>
                    <br>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>

            /*LAS FECHAS*/
            <label>FECHAS</label>
            <br><br>
            <div class="input-daterange input-group">
                <span>DESDE</span>
                <input type="date" name="desde[]"  id="desde" required="required" />
                <span>HASTA</span>
                <input type="date" name="hasta[]" id="hasta" required="required"/>
            </div>


            /*LOS HORARIOS*/
            <label>HORARIO DE INICIO</label>
            <label>HORARIO DE TERMINO</label>
            <br><br>
            <label>Seleccione una hora</label>
            <label>Seleccione una hora</label>
            <br>


            <select name="sel[]" id="options" required="required">
                <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                <option value="08:00:00">08:00:00</option>
                <option value="09:00:00">09:00:00</option>
                <option value="10:00:00">10:00:00</option>
                <option value="11:00:00">11:00:00</option>
                <option value="12:00:00">12:00:00</option>
                <option value="13:00:00">13:00:00</option>
                <option value="14:00:00">14:00:00</option>
                <option value="15:00:00">15:00:00</option>
                <option value="16:00:00">16:00:00</option>
                <option value="17:00:00">17:00:00</option>
                <option value="18:00:00">18:00:00</option>
                <option value="19:00:00">19:00:00</option>
                <option value="20:00:00">20:00:00</option>
                <option value="21:00:00">21:00:00</option>
                <option value="22:00:00">22:00:00</option>
                <option value="23:00:00">23:00:00</option>
            </select>


            /*EL 2do SELECT DE LOS HORARIOS*/
            <select name="sel2[]" id="options2" required="required">
                <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                <option value="09:00:00">09:00:00</option>
                <option value="10:00:00">10:00:00</option>
                <option value="11:00:00">11:00:00</option>
                <option value="12:00:00">12:00:00</option>
                <option value="13:00:00">13:00:00</option>
                <option value="14:00:00">14:00:00</option>
                <option value="15:00:00">15:00:00</option>
                <option value="16:00:00">16:00:00</option>
                <option value="17:00:00">17:00:00</option>
                <option value="18:00:00">18:00:00</option>
                <option value="19:00:00">19:00:00</option>
                <option value="20:00:00">20:00:00</option>
                <option value="21:00:00">21:00:00</option>
                <option value="22:00:00">22:00:00</option>
                <option value="23:00:00">23:00:00</option>
                <option value="24:00:00">24:00:00</option>
            </select>


            /*EL ESTADO DEL HORARIO*/   
            <label>Estado</label>

                <input type="text" value="{{$last_horario->estado_horario_id}}" maxlength="1" required="required" name="estado_horario_id[]">
                <br><br>

                <br><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="REGISTRAR">

            <a href="{{URL::previous()}}">
                <input type="button" value="CANCELAR">
            </a>              
        </div>   
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Por que será que no me guarda 2 registros o 3 o más a la vez, solamente 1. Siendo que a los nombre de los input, y el select, los dejé como un array. `name="nombre[]"`.

De momento eso intento, me debe guardar el **`id`** y la **`cancha_id`** ambos dependiendo de la cantidad de **`checkbox`** que escoja el usuario y asignando sus valores (los de cada checkbox) según sus `id` (que son los `id` de la tabla `cancha`) respectivamente, los demás campos se pueden repetir, pero esos 2 no.

Como dato extra, al momento de hacer esto en mi controlador para ver lo que recibo.

```
public function store(Request $request){

/*
 ...Codigo previo
*/

  dd($request->all());

}
```

Me muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde, en el array del `id` deberían ser 3, ya que en los checkbox son 3, se me debería guardar 3 registros diferentes. Para los demás es campos lo mismo.

Comment: Esta claro que extraer el último registro para optener su id y generar el siguiente es un error, esto va a dar problemas de concurrencia, no me queda clara por qué haces esto, ni la lógica.  Si solo tienes una tabla utiliza un PK autoincremental y te olvidas del id. A primera vista parece que estas duplicando el id que es PK y debe ser único. No se si pretendes hacer algún tipo de relación entre tablas. Es algo confusa tu lógica. Te invito a exponer de forma mar general que tienes y que quieres conseguir.

Comment: @Xerif. Lo hacia porque el autoincremental tambien me daba problema si borraba un registro luego el siguiente se saltaba 1. Pero de momento lo quitare aquello, no tomare el ultimo `id`. Por otro lado lo que tengo es eso. un `select` con unas opciones las cuales me muestran unos checkbox, dependiendo de cada opción es la cantidad que muestra; cada checkbox es un valor del campo `nombre` de mi tabla **`canchas`** y lo que tomo es su `id` y muestro solo el nombre. Luego selecciono una fecha y hora para la reserva de una cancha deportiva. Y finalmente guardo aquello en mi tabla **`horarios`**.

Comment: @Xerif. Debería guardarme la cantidad  que selecciono, por eso trataba de tomar el ultimo `id` y ese agregarle la cantidad de checkbox que seleccionaba, es decir el ultimo registro de mi tabla **`horarios`** su `id` es `4221` el siguiente se guarda como `4222` si antes seleccioné 4 checkbox con aquello trataba que al ultimo `id` genere 4 registros más, para este ejemplo; de esta manera, uno tendrá `id`, `4222` el siguiente será `4223`...

Comment: puedes hacer un dd($request->all()) para ver que es lo que te llega en  el controlador?

Comment: @JorgeBowen. Actualicé la pregunta para mostrar aquello.

Comment: Es dificil ayudarte por no entender del todo pero, supongo que en la captura que adjuntaste, en el array check hay 3 valores, pero en los demas solo hay uno y deberian ser de igual tamaño no?

Comment: @JorgeBowen. Así es. Para ese ejemplo deberían ser 3, en todo. Si hubiese seleccionado solo 2 checkbox serian 2 `id`, 2 fechas y 2 `estados_horario`, y los 2 checkbox que corresponderían al campo de mi tabla, cancha_id. En concreto como resultado en mi base de datos habrían sido 2 registros nuevos. Si hubiese seleccionado 2, si fuese más obviamente serian mas los registros nuevos.

Comment: Tienes algunos errores muy visibles, vamos por parte y comentandolo.

Comment: Evitemos demasiados comentarios, que te parece si nos trasladamos al chat?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85150/discussion-between-jorge-bowen-and-m4urixd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final queda asi, agregamos un array multidimensional en los name con el id del horario

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=> 'horarios.store','method'=> 'POST' ,'class'=>"form-material m-t-40",'name'=>'horario', 'id'=>'horario_id', 'files' => true] ) !!} 

<div> 

<label style="color: black; ">Complejos</label> 
<br> 
<label style="color: grey;">Seleccione un complejo</label> 
<br> 
<select id="complejos" required="required" onchange="MuestraCanchas(event)"> 

<option value="">Seleccione...</option> 
@foreach($complejo as $complejo) 
<option value="{{$complejo->id}}">{{$complejo->nombre}}</option> 

@endforeach 
</select> 
<br><br> 


<div class="DivCheckCanchas" id="DivCheckCanchas"> 
<label style="color: black;" id="label_check">*&nbsp;Seleccione una cancha o campo</label> 
<h6 style="color: grey;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tambien puede seleccionar más de una opción.</h6> 
<br> 
@foreach($campos as $campos) 
<div id="DivCanchas" class="DivCanchas"> 


<input type="checkbox" data-complejo="{{$campos->complejo_id}}" id="{{$campos->nombre}}" value="{{$campos->id}}" name="horario[{{$last_horario->id}}][check][]"> 
<label id="LabelCanchas" style="color: grey;" for="{{$campos->nombre}}">{{$campos->nombre}}</label> 
<br> 
</div> 
@endforeach 
</div> 

<br> 
<label style="color: black;">FECHAS</label> 
<br><br> 
<div class="input-daterange input-group"> 
<span class="input-group-addon bg-info b-0 text-white">DESDE</span> 
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="horario[{{$last_horario->id}}][desde]" id="desde" required="required" /> 
<span class="input-group-addon bg-info b-0 text-white">HASTA</span> 
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="horario[{{$last_horario->id}}][hasta]" id="hasta" required="required"/> 
</div> 

<br><br> 
<label style="color: black;">HORARIO DE INICIO</label> 
<label style="color: black; margin-left: 9cm;">HORARIO DE TERMINO</label> 
<br><br> 
<label>Seleccione una hora</label> 
<label style="margin-left: 8.45cm;">Seleccione una hora</label> 
<br> 


<select name="horario[{{$last_horario->id}}][sel]" id="options" required="required" class="option"> 
<option value="">Seleccione</option> 
<option value="08:00:00">08:00:00</option> 
<option value="09:00:00">09:00:00</option> 
<option value="10:00:00">10:00:00</option> 
<option value="11:00:00">11:00:00</option> 
<option value="12:00:00">12:00:00</option> 
<option value="13:00:00">13:00:00</option> 
<option value="14:00:00">14:00:00</option> 
<option value="15:00:00">15:00:00</option> 
<option value="16:00:00">16:00:00</option> 
<option value="17:00:00">17:00:00</option> 
<option value="18:00:00">18:00:00</option> 
<option value="19:00:00">19:00:00</option> 
<option value="20:00:00">20:00:00</option> 
<option value="21:00:00">21:00:00</option> 
<option value="22:00:00">22:00:00</option> 
<option value="23:00:00">23:00:00</option> 
</select> 

<select name="horario[{{$last_horario->id}}][sel2]" id="options2" required="required" class="option2"> 
<option value="">Seleccione...</option> 
<option value="09:00:00">09:00:00</option> 
<option value="10:00:00">10:00:00</option> 
<option value="11:00:00">11:00:00</option> 
<option value="12:00:00">12:00:00</option> 
<option value="13:00:00">13:00:00</option> 
<option value="14:00:00">14:00:00</option> 
<option value="15:00:00">15:00:00</option> 
<option value="16:00:00">16:00:00</option> 
<option value="17:00:00">17:00:00</option> 
<option value="18:00:00">18:00:00</option> 
<option value="19:00:00">19:00:00</option> 
<option value="20:00:00">20:00:00</option> 
<option value="21:00:00">21:00:00</option> 
<option value="22:00:00">22:00:00</option> 
<option value="23:00:00">23:00:00</option> 
<option value="24:00:00">24:00:00</option> 
</select> 


<br><br><br> 
<label style="color: black;">Estado</label> 
<br> 

<input type="text" value="2" class="form-control form-control-line" style="width: 10%;" onkeypress="return numeros(event)" maxlength="1" required="required" name="horario[{{$last_horario->id}}][estado_horario_id]"> 
<br><br><br> 
<input type="submit" id="btn-success" value="REGISTRAR"> 

<a href="{{URL::previous()}}"> 
<input type="button" id="btn-cancelar" value="CANCELAR"> 
</a> 
<br><br> 
</div> 

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

En el controlador

```
<?php

public function store(Request $request){

    try {

        foreach($request->horario as $id_horario=>$row){
            // RECORREMOS EL PRIMER NIVEL PARA SACAR LOS PRIMEROS VALORES QUE NO SON ARRAY
            foreach($row['check'] as $check){
                // HACEMOS ESTE SEGUNDO LOOP PARA SACAR TODOS LOS VALUES DEL ARRAY CHECK

$horarios = new HorariosNew(); 
$horarios->hora_inicio = $row['desde'].' '.$row['sel']; 
$horarios->hora_fin = $row['hasta'].' '.$row['sel2']; 
$horarios->estado_horario_id = $row['estado_horario_id']; 
$horarios->cancha_id = $check; 
$horarios->save();

                //COMO SABRAS AHORA, NO HACE FALTA PONER ID, SI TU TABLA TIENE AUTOINCREMENT, NO ES NECESARIO
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {

         Session::flash('error', 'Hubo un error desconocido, no se pudo registrar el horario');
         return redirect()->route('horarios.store');

    }

        Session::flash('message', 'Se agregó correctamente el horario');
        return redirect()->route('horarios.store');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

primero debes debes obtener tu check[] en el controlador, ese es el que vas a poner en el foreach, si tu seleccion tiene 3 check, y los 3 los seleccionas el debe de dar 3 vueltas para insertar la informacion q tiene el formulario con cada check, en ves de poner el `$request->get('sel')` en el foreach, tienes q poner  es `$request->get('check')`.. este ultimo es el q tiene el total de vueltas q va a dar tu foreach para insertar.

En el dump que muestras te lo dice todo `check = array(0=>0,1=>1,2=>9)`

Entonces el foreach hace esto para la primera vuelta:

```
foreach(check[0] as item){ inserta $item = 0; }
```

para la segunda vuelta

```
foreach(check[1] as item){ inserta $item = 1; }
```

para la tercera vuelta

```
foreach(check[2] as item){ inserta $item = 9; }
```

Espero te sirva, cualquier otra duda comentas.

Comment: Me arroja otro error. `Undefined offset: 1` Y el error me resalta esta linea:  **`$horarios->hora_inicio = $request->get('desde')[$key].' '.$request->get('sel')[$key];`**

Comment: Bueno tienes q trabajar con js, para hacer q te funcione, al momento de tu seleccionar el complejo te arme un div llamado horarios y te ponga el total de horario para cada cancha q hay ejemplo, si tienes 3 canchas el te armara 3 div horario[] con lainformacion.. al tu enviar los check, te funcione lo del key.. ejemplo seria foreach($request->get('check') as $key => $item) $request->horario[$key] luego de esto es q vas a insertar las fechas y las horas, entonces el va a capturar la informacion de acuerdo a la posicion q tenga el $request->horario..

Comment: o si no lo dejas como lo tenias, y sacas el foreach($request->check as $key => $item){} pruebalo asi, como lo tenias antes pero le vas a agregar el $request->check